# Changing text color inside a div, $%

Tags: jquery, regex

If I have the following div:

```
<div id="target">
red <br>

blue <br>

green <br>

</div>
```

and I'd like to add a script which changes each color word, to be in its own color ('red' will be red and so on).

The solution on the site is this:

```
var target=$('#target');
target.html(target.html().replace(/red/,"<span style='color:red'>$&</span>").replace(/blue/,"<span style='color:blue'>$&</span>").replace(/green/,"<span style='color:green'>$&</span>"));
```

Could anyone explain this? In my solution I added spans with the correct text color, and wrote the word (for example red) inside the span. But in this solution they added these symbols, $%, and I don't understand how that works.

Comment: `$&` Inserts the matched substring. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$&` stands for the matches. for example, `red` for `/red/`

Answer (score 0):

here `$&` stands for the matches

EXAMPLE:`red for /red/`

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$&` is a Regular expression.
It returns the last matched characters from any regular expression search

In this scenario `red` for `/red/`

Answer (score -1):

You use this solution alternate to `REGX`,

```
$(function(){

    var xStr="";

    $.each($("#target").html().split("<br>"),function(xIndex,xVal)
           {
               if(xVal.trim() !== "")
               {
                   xStr += "<span style='color:"+ xVal +"'>"+ xVal +"</span><br>"
               }
           });

    $("#target").html(xStr);

});
```

Reference: [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/),[Split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2XCx/)